# How to setup Internet gateway Windows Server 2008 by Routing and Remote Access

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, routing

Server has 2 NICs:
One (WAN) connected to ISP:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 87.110.xxx.xx

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 87.110.xxx.xx

Second (LAN) connected to switch and other LAN hosts:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.1

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Under enabled Routing and Remote Access, through wizard configured NAT access for private interface.

However Hosts on LAN can't be ping'ed, as well RDP from server to LAN hosts not working

Any other configs necessary?
Added:
Firewall is switched off

## IPv4 Route Table

Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    87.110.xxx.xx    87.110.xxx.xx    276
    87.110.xxx.xx  255.255.255.248         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
    87.110.xxx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
    87.110.xxx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
    87.110.xxx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        192.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.20.1    276
     192.168.20.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.1    276
  192.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.1    276
   195.122.xxx.xx  255.255.255.240         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
   195.122.xxx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.20.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     87.110.xxx.xx    276

## 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.1    276

Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric

## 0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    87.110.180.49  Default

Comment: Assuming this isn't just a firewall issue (easy enough to check by disabling it) if you fix the ping, the RDP is likely to work too. Focus on the connections. Windows forces the ".1" for internet connection sharing, but otherwise I wouldn't suggest using it;  also make sure that you don't already have something at that address. And Welcome to Superuser! ... but please add what troubleshooting steps you've taken etc. (There's an expectation here that you've tried to do your own research & troubleshooting first.)

Comment: Yes, firewall is switched off